# WatchKit : presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestion slowed my app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, dictation, wkinterfacelabel

I use a presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestion in my watch app in Swift.
It works but my app is really slow after the dictation.

There is my code :

```
func dictation() {
        presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions([], allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (selectedAnswers) -> Void in
            if ((selectedAnswers != nil) && (selectedAnswers!.count>0) ){
                if selectedAnswers![0] is String {
                    self.label.setText((selectedAnswers![0] as! String))
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I just display my text in a label. But, between the time where I press on "Done" in the dictation screen and the time where I can see my text, there is at leat a second.

I saw that is really quickly in Apple apps like Mail or Messages.

I saw that my watch CPU is near by 50% during the dictation and near 100% when I press "Done". My app doesn't consume CPU during this step. The CPU is consume by an other app (I suppose dictation).

Do you know how I can improve this response time ?

Comment: Are you using a real device? Or Simulator?

Comment: I am using a device. I think that dictation can't work with simulator.

Comment: An idea @SeyyedParsaNeshaei ?

Comment: @PierreCharpentiew Did you try using Instruments to log your app and see the system consuming tasks?

Comment: I tried but I didn't see anything.. It's not really explicit. I'm not an expert of Instruments so, if you think about something that I could see, tell me

Comment: @SeyyedParsaNeshaei when I follow my app with Instruments, I don't see any consumption of CPU during dictation. My CPU increase when I finish dictation after "black" time.